# Creating a series containing numpy nans and pandas NaTs defaults all to pandas NaTs; is this intentional?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Pandas version 1.0.3

For example...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.DataFrame([pd.Series(dict(a=pd.NaT, b=np.nan))])
```

Some kind of spooky type inference gives both a and b as NaT.

```
    a   b
0   NaT NaT
```

Of course then adding actual float values in subsequent series to 'b' will result it having the dtype object not the dtype float you might have assumed.

This behavior looks like a bug to me but is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that you **first create a series**. All items of this series have the same type (`datetime64[ns]` in our case), hence the `np.nan` gets converted to `NaT`. See also [Inserting missing data](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html#inserting-missing-data):

> Likewise, datetime containers will always use NaT.

Your series that you then convert to a dataframe:

```
pd.Series(dict(a=pd.NaT, b=np.nan))
#a   NaT
#b   NaT
#dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

Without series:

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[pd.NaT], b=[np.nan]))
#    a   b
#0 NaT NaN
```

Comment: Yes, I see but this type coercion seems arbitrary/inconsistent to me.  If I set disparate types in a Series then the type of that Series should be 'object' (IMHO).    If I build the dataframe as you suggest and take the first row using iloc[0] I get an 'object' Series containing a NaT and a NaN.

Comment: But this is the way object creation works in pandas. If you do `pd.Series([1,2.0])` then the integer `1` also gets converted to float `1.0`.

Comment: If we do `pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[pd.NaT], b=[np.nan]))` we create *two* columns, each with its own type. Of course, if you take rows of differently typed columns the result will always be mixed type (object).

Comment: True, but if I do pd.Series(dict(a=pd.NaT, b='Hello')) I get an 'object' type Series automatically.  It just happens in my case to arbitrarily* force the dtype to datetime64 and not object (like I think it should).  *By arbitrarily I mean why not force it to float, it's got two values, it's just making a choice based on no information.

Comment: Yes, there might be some arbitrarity here. I guess the reason that you get a mixed type for `pd.Series(dict(a=pd.NaT, b='Hello'))` is that there's no special missing value type for strings (unless you use the new type `string`) and there's no clear way to convert pd.NaT to a string value. But this is just speculation, maybe you find further insight if you dig into the source code.